# How can I influence minimax algorithm to prefer immediate rewards?

Tags: java, algorithm, artificial-intelligence

I am implementing the minimax for a Stratego game (where the computer has perfect knowledge of all the pieces). However, I find that the computer will often not attack a piece that it can easily destroy. From what I understand, the minimax scores comes from the leaf nodes of a move tree (where each level is a turn and each score for the leaf node is calculated using an evaluation function for the board in that position). So if I have a depth of 3 levels, the computer can choose to attack on move 1 or attack on move 3. According to the minimax algorithm, it has the same score associated with it (the resulting board position has the same score). So how do I influence the minimax algorithm to prefer immediate rewards over eventual rewards? i.e. I would like the score to decay over time, but with the way minimax works I don't see how this is possible. Minimax always uses the leaf nodes to determine the intermediate nodes.

Comment: If it's definitely possible three moves from now, why waste a move on it right away? A possible answer: you worry that the opponent might stop it from happening. But if they can do that, then the min-step will reveal that fact, and you will find it attractive to take that reward before the opponent can prevent it.

Comment: [this article](http://neverstopbuilding.com/minimax) describes a loosely related topic (make the AI take the longest run, if it can't win). The same approach can be used here: add a factor of depth to your scoring-function, if you absolutely want to create a shortsighted opponent, such that gains within the next few steps are counted higher. However in general a minimax-AI knows what it does (if implemented properly), so there isn't much to gain here, appart from an easier game.

Comment: @DanielWagner, the problem I have is that each turn, the computer continually chooses to wait to make the kill, resulting in it indefinitely not killing the opponent piece (I'll kill it next time, I'll kill it next time, etc)

Comment: That does make sense what you are saying though. Now that I think about it, the piece it won't attack is trapped. But I'd still like the computer to prefer the earlier kill over the later kill, all things equal. Stratego is sometimes a race to kill more pieces, and if the computer is wasting turns, it may be giving up other opportunities in the future.

Comment: Another example of this behavior is when the computer can capture the flag, it will often not care about about capturing it and another piece will move, knowing that it can always capture the flag next turn, then next turn, then next turn. In this situation, it makes perfect sense to be greedy and capture the flag immediately, because that ends the game, but the computer doesn't.

Comment: @sam that specific case is typically handled by using iterative deepening (first do minimax with depth limit 1, then with 2, then with 3, etc.). That way, you can stop the process as soon as u find a terminal state (or run out of thinking time), and it will always prefer short wins over long wins. Though you can also change the evaluation function to return (M - d) for the winner, where M is some large constant (say, 10000), and d is the depth of the terminal game state. For all other cases... see my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by others in the comments, minimax should be able to notice if there is a danger in delaying to capture a piece automatically, and changing the evaluation function to force it to prefer earlier captures is likely to be detrimental to playing performance.

Still, if you really want to do it, I think the only way would be to start storing extra information in your game states (not only the board). You'll want to store timestamps in memory for every game state which allow you to still tell in hindsight exactly at what time (in which turn) a piece was previously captured. Using that information you could implement a decay factor in the evaluation function used in leaf nodes of the search tree.

A different solution may be to simply make sure that you search to an even depth level; 2 or 4 instead of 3. That way, your algorithm will always evaluate game states where the opponent had the last move, instead of your computer player. All evaluations will become more pessimistic, and this may encourage your agent to prefer earlier rewards in some situations.

This effect where odd search depths typically result in different evaluations from even search depths is referred to as the [odd-even effect](https://chessprogramming.wikispaces.com/Odd-Even+Effect). You may be interested in looking into that more (though it's typically discussed for different reasons than what your question is about).